# Sticky-top on two rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried many different ways to have two rows become sticky-top and I just can't seem to have any success with it.

Here is what I currently have:
**Default**:
[image]

**Sticky-top**:
[image]

Problem: How do I make the Junior/Mid/Senior row also be a sticky top but have it below the 'Core Competencies'? When I apply a sticky top to the second row, it displays above.

**Correct**: Both rows to be sticky-top without overlapping each other.
[image]

**Please run the below code to view the problem**.

```css
.heading {
    background-color: #00C6D7;
}
h4, h6 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.container {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(77,72,69,0.2), 0 6px 10px rgba(77,72,69,0.15);
}
span {
    font-size: smaller;
}
.col-md-3 {
    padding-top: .6rem!important;
    padding-bottom: .6rem!important;
}
.col-md-2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.bl {
    border-left: 1px solid lightgray;
}
.bb {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #00C6D7;
}
.bg-white {
    background-color: white;
}
.mainText {
    font-style: italic;
    color: #00C6D7;
}
.bg-fhdark {
    background-color: #5E6A71;
}
.title {
    color: #A2AD00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="py-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row sticky-top">
        <div class="col-md-10 text-white text-left py-2 heading">
            <h4 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Core Competencies</h4>
            <span class="small">Our goal was to develop a set of core competencies that are consistent across the agency amd reflect growth as a priority.
                Some competencies, such as negotiating, listening and interpersonal communication are not included but are considered baseline skills.
                The Core Competencies consist of four main areas: Client, Talent, Business Development and Growth, and Finance and Operations.
                Each area is outlined at the junior, mid and senior level.
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center py-2 heading">
            <img style="width: inherit" src="" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row bg-white">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">
            <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold title">Junior</h6>
            <span>Valued Colleague and Practitioner</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">
            <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold title">Mid</h6>
            <span>Trusted Colleague; Proven and Creative Practitioner</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl text-left">
            <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold title">Senior</h6>
            <span>Trusted Client Advisor and Partner; Proven Agency Leader</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row py-1 bg-fhdark">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-left text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">Client</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 bb">
            <span>Client Focus, Strategic Counsel and Consultancy</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">1</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">1</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 bb">
            <span>Integrated Strategy and Account Management</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">2</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">2</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <span>Creativity and Innovation</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">3</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">3</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row py-1 bg-fhdark">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-left text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">Talent</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 bb">
            <span>Manage Full Talent LifeCycle</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">4</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">4</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 bb">
            <span>Professional Development/Developing and Empowering</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">5</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">5</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <span>Self-Leadership</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">6</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">6</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row py-1 bg-fhdark">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-left text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">Business Development and Growth</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 bb">
            <span>New Business Strategy</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">7</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">7</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">7</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 bb">
            <span>Prospecting</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">8</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">8</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">8</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 bb">
            <span>New Business Pitch Preparation, Participation and Leaderhip</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">9</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">9</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">9</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <span>Organic Growth</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">10</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">10</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">10</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row py-1 bg-fhdark">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-left text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">Finance and Operations</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 bb">
            <span>Financial Management of Accounts (Account Profitability, Realization, Budgets)</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">11</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">11</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">11</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <span>Staffing and Resource Planning</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">12</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">12</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">12</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just put the other div into the `sticky` element?

like this,

```css
body { background: #f2f2f2; }
.heading {
    background-color: #00C6D7;
}
h4, h6 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.container {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(77,72,69,0.2), 0 6px 10px rgba(77,72,69,0.15);
}
span {
    font-size: smaller;
}
.col-md-3 {
    padding-top: .6rem!important;
    padding-bottom: .6rem!important;
}
.col-md-2 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.bl {
    border-left: 1px solid lightgray;
}
.bb {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #00C6D7;
}
.bg-white {
    background-color: white;
}
.mainText {
    font-style: italic;
    color: #00C6D7;
}
.bg-fhdark {
    background-color: #5E6A71;
}
.title {
    color: #A2AD00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="py-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row sticky-top">
        <div class="col-md-10 text-white text-left py-2 heading">
            <h4 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Core Competencies</h4>
            <span class="small">Our goal was to develop a set of core competencies that are consistent across the agency amd reflect growth as a priority.
                Some competencies, such as negotiating, listening and interpersonal communication are not included but are considered baseline skills.
                The Core Competencies consist of four main areas: Client, Talent, Business Development and Growth, and Finance and Operations.
                Each area is outlined at the junior, mid and senior level.
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2 text-center py-2 heading">
            <img style="width: inherit" src="" />
        </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="row bg-white">
    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 bl">
     <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold title">Junior</h6>
     <span>Valued Colleague and Practitioner</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 bl">
     <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold title">Mid</h6>
     <span>Trusted Colleague; Proven and Creative Practitioner</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 bl text-left">
     <h6 class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold title">Senior</h6>
     <span>Trusted Client Advisor and Partner; Proven Agency Leader</span>
    </div>
   </div></div>
      </div>
  
      <div class="row py-1 bg-fhdark">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-left text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">Client</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 bb">
            <span>Client Focus, Strategic Counsel and Consultancy</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">1</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">1</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 bb">
            <span>Integrated Strategy and Account Management</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">2</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">2</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <span>Creativity and Innovation</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">3</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">3</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row py-1 bg-fhdark">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-left text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">Talent</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 bb">
            <span>Manage Full Talent LifeCycle</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">4</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">4</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 bb">
            <span>Professional Development/Developing and Empowering</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">5</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">5</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">5</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <span>Self-Leadership</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">6</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">6</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row py-1 bg-fhdark">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-left text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">Business Development and Growth</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 bb">
            <span>New Business Strategy</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">7</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">7</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">7</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 bb">
            <span>Prospecting</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">8</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">8</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">8</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 bb">
            <span>New Business Pitch Preparation, Participation and Leaderhip</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">9</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">9</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">9</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <span>Organic Growth</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">10</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">10</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">10</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row py-1 bg-fhdark">
            <div class="col-md-12 text-left text-uppercase font-weight-bold text-white">Finance and Operations</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 bb">
            <span>Financial Management of Accounts (Account Profitability, Realization, Budgets)</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">11</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">11</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl bb">11</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <span>Staffing and Resource Planning</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">12</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">12</div>
        <div class="col-md-3 bl">12</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've tried this @Oneezy and the formatting gets corrupt as in the 'Run code snippet'.

Comment: I've updated the code to have correct formatting. does that work for you?